# Background context and Save URL in URL hacking

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-button, url, urlhacking, list-button

I have a URL list button that pops up the New Account contact relationship form.
Below is the URL:

```
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/AccountContactRelation/new?backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Account/{Account.Id}/view')}
```

When I use `Account.Id` in the URL for the backgroundcontext, below is the image which I am getting. The background image is not getting displayed.

[image]

The URL for that form is: `https://testabc.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/AccountContactRelation/new?backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F%7B%21Account.Id%7D%2Fview&count=2`

If observed, the **Account.Id** merge field is not getting merged properly in the above URL. It is working fine if I hardcode the account Id.

1. How do I make the Merge field work?
2. The additional question is that, How do I take back the screen to the Account.Id record after the record is saved successfully.

Comment: Can you try {URLFOR('/lightning/o/AccountContactRelation/new?backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Account/'+{!Account.Id}+'/view')}

Comment: It is not working. It is throwing an syntax error.

Comment: I'm able to create new button with above syntax. Check here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NznYFvXHRVdUlFSd5_D9qwQRYHEeFjjR/view?usp=sharing..

Comment: Although button is not working

Comment: The button should be {!URLFOR and you missed "!"